# Trigger partition creation on table insert SQL Server tabular model

Tags: sql-server, triggers, ssas, partition, ssas-tabular

I have a SSAS tabular model, and I want to create a partition on the fact and dimension tables automatically when a new row is inserted into a table (the table contains the project name, I have a cube that stores many projects since they have the same structure, I need to create a partition after any insertion of a new project in the project table, to be able then to process the cube only on one project).

I did some research, and all I found was xlma code, which does not help me because the script that is generated for my version of SSAS is in m query.

Can anyone please help me with anything useful, steps to achieve that, article..

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The M query is embedded in the TMSL partition definition.  Script out the table in SSMS to see how this works.

[image]

See generally [Create and manage tabular model partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/create-and-manage-tabular-model-partitions?view=asallproducts-allversions).  You can create the new partitions using [TMSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tmsl/tabular-model-scripting-language-tmsl-reference?view=asallproducts-allversions#how-to-use-tmsl) or the [Tabular Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tom/create-tables-partitions-and-columns-in-a-tabular-model?view=asallproducts-allversions)

Comment: thank you, but what i need to do is to trigger the creation of partition after insertion on a table, for example an ssis workflow that creates partitions on tables after insertion on another table, it takes the value inserted, and creates partition by filtering on that value.

Comment: Cool.  Here's a sample to help you get started: https://github.com/Microsoft/Analysis-Services/tree/master/AsPartitionProcessing

Comment: thank you i ll check that